# Passing a function argument to other arguments which are functions themselves

Tags: r, function, arguments

Assume I have an outer function that has a numeric argument and an argument which is a function itself (inner function). How can I pass the value of the numeric argument of the outer function as an argument to the inner function? Consider this toy example:

```
innerfun <- function(M){
 1:M
}

outerfun <- function(x, fun){
 x * fun
}

outerfun(x = 3, fun = innerfun(M = 3)) ## works
outerfun(x = 3, fun = innerfun(M = x)) ## error because innerfun can't find 'x'
outerfun(x = 3, fun = innerfun(M = get("x"))) ## doesn't work either...
```

So what I want to do is to call innerfun at the moment the arguments of outerfun are evaluated, using those outerfun-arguments in the call to innerfun. Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do something like this :

```
outerfun <- function(x, fun,...){
  x * fun(x,...)
}
innerfun <- function(M){
  seq_len(M) ## safer than 1:M
}
outerfun(x=3, innerfun)
[1] 3 6 9
```

Note that If inner function has more than one argument, it still works :

```
innerfun2 <- function(M,Z){
  seq(M+Z)
}
outerfun(x=3, innerfun2,Z=3)
[1]  3  6  9 12 15 18
```

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the easiest solution. I just didn't think of exploiting R's lazy evaluation by passing innerfun as a function call without arguments. Once innerfun is evaluated inside the body of outerfun (instead of during the initialization of outerfun), it is easier to pass the arguments.

Comment: @WolfgangPößnecker nothing to do with lazy evaluation here

Answer (score 0):

Add a "global" variable:

```
param = 3;
outerfun(x = param, fun = innerfun(M = param))
```