# Passing a function (distribution) to other arguments which are functions themselves

Tags: r

I am trying to do multiple samples of a distribution with a function. The trouble I am having is that when I pass the distribution into the function all the means come out the same as it appears my distribution is not being run each time inside the for loop.
Test line:

```
test(100,100,dist = rbinom(x, 1, 0.50))
```

Code

```
test = function(N, n, dist){
  means = matrix(rep(0,times=N,nrow=N,ncol=1))
  x = n
  for(i in 1:N){
    means[i,1]<- mean(dist)
    print(means[i,1])
  }
}
```

This question is similar to [Passing a function argument to other arguments which are functions themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075331/passing-a-function-argument-to-other-arguments-which-are-functions-themselves) but I seem to be having a different type of problem.

Comment: What is your intended output? It's difficult to understand the goal of this code, and therefore difficult to help.

Comment: the means from each sample distribution.

Comment: in your case, `dist` needs to be evaluated just once on the first iteration and thereafter you will have a constant numeric vector. You could say `dist = function(x) {rbinom(x, 1, 0.5)}`, which would be different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to pass function and parameters separately. E.g.

```
test(100, 100, dist = rbinom, list(1, 0.5))

test = function(N, n, dist, ...){
  means = matrix(rep(0,times=N,nrow=N,ncol=1))
  x = n
  for(i in 1:N){
    means[i, 1] <- mean(do.call(dist, c(x, ...)))
    print(means[i, 1])
  }
}
```